# Ensure file create permissions of program launched from batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, permissions

I have a simple batch file that labunches an old DOS binary.  Forever, the .exe has been launched with `start \b` from the .bat file.

Recently, I have found that the DOS program crashes when trying to create some files, for some of the directories from which the batch file is launched.  The program *modifies* files everywhere just fine.  It's quite possible the DOS program is doing something stupid-- it doesn't emit useful information, it just crashes with a c0000005 access violation-- but I have to live with it.

With a little debug, it's clear that changing `start \b` to `runas /savecred /user:ssliva` blesses the DOS program with the file creation permissions it needs to not crash, even though I'm already logged in.  User ssliva (me) is an admin on the box.

Is there a way to get this DOS program working for all directories and all users again?  I don't want to hardcode user names in the batch file, so ideally I'd be able to discover what permissions are different where the program is crashing.

I would think the issue is with the directory's permissions, but `icacls` indicates that the directory that needs `runas [admin]` has identical permissions to the directory where `start`works.  Users are (RX). I'm at a loss as to why file creation is causing an app crash in some directories but not others unless it's something other than folder permissions.

Comment: Sounds like you need to run the batch file elevated, i.e., using the "run as admin" option.  If you create a shortcut to the batch file, you can set a shortcut property to make this the default.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - thanks for the comment.  The batch file takes a command line parameter that it passes to the DOS program, so no option for that.   I *did*, however poke into things more and discover that perhaps there are some environment variables used by the DOS program that apparently have blessed some directories and not others, and I have updated the batch file to do that configuration.  (Still inexplicable why the elevated permissions worked, but alas.)

Comment: If the batch file takes a command line parameter, then presumably you are running it from a command window - so if elevation is required, you would want to run it from an *elevated* command window.  Obviously if you can reconfigure it to not require elevation that's even better. :-)  (Tip: to start an elevated command window, press the Windows key, type "cmd" and press CONTROL-SHIFT-ENTER.  On Windows 8+ there's a more direct shortcut but I don't remember it offhand.)

Comment: That may be the general solution I was looking for.  Wrong box to test right now.